# What algorithms do you know for beltway reconstruction?

Tags: ds.algorithms, nt.number-theory, comp-number-theory

I've faced the beltway reconstruction problem and I've developed a simple backtrack algorithm, what algorithms do you know for this problem? 
**Beltway Reconstruction Problem**: 
Assume there is a set of non-identical integers between 0 and N, we only have pairwise distances of points of that set mod N, How can we reconstruct the original set using this?

Comment: It's not quite the same problem, but some of the suggestions at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17307/how-to-obtain-the-unknown-values-a-i-b-j-given-an-unordered-list-of-a-i-b-j-m?rq=1 look helpful.

Comment: [simultaneously cross-posted](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136156/what-algorithms-do-you-know-for-beltway-reconstruction) on MO.

Comment: Our [site policy](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/231/) prohibits ***simultaneous*** **crossposting**: it duplicates effort and fractures discussion. Crossposting is permitted after a week has passed without a satisfying answer elsewhere. When crossposting please summarize the relevant discussions from other sites in your question and link to the copies in both directions.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this rule. Now what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Paul Lemke Steven S. Skiena Warren D. Smith, [Reconstructing Sets From Interpoint Distances](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.20.6172), gave backtracking algorithm that runs in time $O(n^n \log n)$ for the beltway reconstruction problem. As far as I know, this is the best known. The exact complexity of the problem is not known. It is not known to be in $P$ and neither known to be $NP$-complete.

Comment: Thanks. I've read these two papers: Reconstruction of Integers from Pairwise Distances & Reconstructing Sets From Interpoint Distances. Do you know any other references?

Comment: No. I am not aware of any more recent references.